# PromQL query giving multiple data points within a week

Tags: prometheus, grafana, latency, promql

[image]

I want to calculate the **average p95** for `/my-api` over the last week, say Mon - Sun, but when I am plotting below query it's giving me multiple data points even within a week.

I expect that this would give me 1 data point for 7 days.

**Query**

```
avg_over_time(histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{uri="/my-api",job="kubernetes-pods", service="service-name"}[1m])) by (le))[1w]) * 1000
```

I even tried to make **min-internal to 1w** and after doing this it's saying "No Data"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It gives you a result of "previous week" in relation to each step in graph.

If you want a single point for whole week, you can set *Min interval* to `1w`. Please notice, that this will enforce blocks to be at least 7 days "wide", but this doesn't ensure alignment with Mondays.

Comment: Ok after setting the min-interval I am not getting any data. Also you mean if I check the value at Monday, 00:00 in current 15 seconds interval it will give me for last weeks data right.

Comment: @tusharRawat, Set time range of your dashboard for more than 7 days and you'll see result.

Comment: Yeah I have used for 30 days only, still giving graph with no data.

Comment: As soon as I make min-interval beyond 23hours, it shows no data, on 30 days time window.